# JQuery + CSS - Elastic/Bounce scrolling on with overflow:auto

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

Is there a way of having a scrolling effect that bounces elastically at the end of a scrollable div rather like the iOS system?

Comment: +1 This is also known as "elastic" or "rubber band" scrolling, but the official name in Apple Developer docs is Bounce Scroll. Video example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjuNGpU29Mk and also seen in this WP7 demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymtCIwi42Zk

Comment: For Future people reading this - don't forget Apple patented this bounce scroll and love law suits on anything or anyone

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about the bounce effect, but this could be a place to start.

http://www.developria.com/2010/09/elastic-scrolling-with-javascr.html